# Word for the act of disabling something

Tags: single-word-requests

If the act of *deleting* is *deletion*, is there a word for the act of *disabling* something?

We're extending an existing UI that has buttons such as `Confirm Deletion` and `Confirm Addition` and are stuck on what to put for the disable confirmation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider using **disabling** as its noun.

Actual usage for [iPad and iPhone](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/04/turn-off-dictation-on-ipad-iphone/):

> For **Disabling**: Tap “Turn Off” to ***confirm disabling*** of the
>   feature

Comment: I was going to give the same answer so I upvoted. *Deleting* is a noun too. The suffix *-ing* is a productive suffix that you can form verbal nouns with.

Comment: Thanks @Rathony, seeing it in that context really helped!

Comment: @ChrisHaas My pleasure. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 5):

The noun form of *disable* is [*disablement*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disable). Note that gerunds can also be used as nouns if there's not a noun form of the verb.

All three of `Confirm Disable`, `Confirm Disabling` and `Confirm Disablement` would be understood. The last two sound better to me.

Comment: To me as an ESL person, Disablement sounds very odd :)

Answer (score 2):

**"Confirm Disable,"** while not *elegant* would certainly be understood by your reader/user.

Comment: IMO this is much more intuitive than "Confirm Disabling" and *much* less clunky than "Confirm Disablement".

Comment: Thank you. My intention was to keep it short to better match with "Confirm Deletion" and "Confirm Addition."